# Implementation of Search Dialog

Tags: android

I am developing an android app which requires search functionality.
My app contains action bar and I have search button on it. On click of search button, I want search dialog to appear on top and do some search for me.
I need help in implementing this.
I tried the Google I/O sched project, but its too complex for me. 
Can anybody help me develop a simple search dialog.

Also, I want the search to have 2 search options.
I have 2 different lists containing different data. So, I want to make search on both these lists but separately. 
Check out this [twitter app](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html), the search bar has 2 options, it can search from tweets or people, I want some thing like thatA.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go through these two links they will give a basic idea of how to add a searching functionality in your application.The idea can then be extended to have search based on two buttons.
http://shapingclouds.com/2009/10/19/how-add-searchmanager-quick-search-to-your-android-application/

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

After you have done with above two links go through these links.They will give you idea of Twitter application's search.You can then extend the idea to create your own search functionality.
http://www.vogella.de/blog/2010/02/15/twitter-android/

I hope this may help you.

Comment: 1st 2 links are very helpful. Thanks a lot.
3rd link doesnt actually have search functionality.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi, the http://www.vogella.de/blog/2010/02/15/twitter-android/ link is broken, could you replace it please

Comment: The first link (http://shapingclouds.com/2009/10/19/how-add-searchmanager-quick-search-to-your-android-application/) is broken